# как передать в скрипт long string через командную строку

Tags: python, bash

```
python3 script.py -str longlongstr*10000

bash: /usr/bin/python3: Слишком длинный список аргументов
```

как это сделать?

Comment: например, записывайте в файл и передавайте имя файла.